Detect route change inside inner/partial component (VueRoute 3 in Nuxt 2.14)
Issue
The Vue component PartialComponent has another InnerPartialComponent that, in turn, has a Google Recaptcha (i.e. VueRecaptcha) inside that actually is an old vue-recaptcha (v1.3.0). So, in general:
management.vue
> SomeComponent
>> PartialComponent
>>> InnerPartialComponent
>>>> VueRecaptcha

Due to Vue Route transition scroll-x-reverse-transition of management.vue that comes from Vuetify, the following happens on page change:

The captcha "jumps" on the page during the transition. Therefore, I guess, it would be appropriate to use v-show or v-if on the captcha VueRecaptcha component to hide the element during route change, but am still searching for an adequate approach.
The reCaptcha DOM element should go right with the component transition, but it jumps to the middle of the page for some unknown reason possibly due to some CSS property change during the Vuetify transition.
I am trying to find a proper way to hide it before the transition to, at least, don't let it "jump".
Question
There's a hope this project will reach an upgrade point, but until that moment, what would be an adequate option to replace the workaround and catch the route change to hide the captcha during the transition?
Despite the route change technique, which is still crucially interesting, what would cause the captcha to "jump" in the first place? It seems there's no custom CSS property that replaces the Vuetify's styles that would modify the captcha position so much.
And... thank you very much for a suggestion in advance! ✨
Environment
There's a legacy nuxt (v2.14.6) project with vue-route (v3.4.3), module nuxt-i18n (v6.15.1), and vuetify (v2.7.2). Indeed... Some history here!
A page change there is being done via push:
<!-- File: ./pages/user/_slug/index.vue -->

<script lang="ts">
import mixins from 'vue-typed-mixins';
import SomeMixin from '~/mixins/SomeMixin';

export default mixins(SomeMixin).extend({
  name: 'UserPage',
  // ...
  methods: {
    async submit(): Promise<void> {
      const response = await this.$api(/* ... */) // ...
      // ...
  
      this.$router.push(
        this.localePath({
          name: 'user-slug-management',
          params: {
            slug: String(this.user.slug ?? this.user.id)
          }
        })
      );
    }
    // ...
  }
  // ...
});
</script>

Another page has the path name in head:
<!-- File: ./pages/user/_slug/management.vue -->

<template>
  <div>
    <SomeComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import mixins from 'vue-typed-mixins';
import SomeMixin from '~/mixins/SomeMixin';
import config from '~/utils/config';
import SomeComponent from '~/components/SomeComponent.vue'

export default mixins(SomeMixin).extend({
  transition: 'scroll-x-reverse-transition',
  name: 'UserManagement',

  components: {
    SomeComponent
  },

  head(): any {
    const canonicalPathOptions = {
      name: 'user-slug-management',
      params: {
        slug: String(this.user.slug ?? this.user.id)
      }
    }

    return {
      title: this.$t('this.title'),
      meta: [{ hid: 'robots', name: 'robots', content: 'noindex' }],

      link: [
        {
          rel: 'canonical',
          href: config.BASE_URL + this.localePath(canonicalPathOptions),
          hid: 'canonical'
        },
        {
          rel: 'alternate',
          hreflang: 'en',
          content: config.BASE_URL + this.localePath(canonicalPathOptions, 'en')
        },
        {
          rel: 'alternate',
          hreflang: 'lt',
          content: config.BASE_URL + this.localePath(canonicalPathOptions, 'lt')
        },
        // ...
      ]
    }
  }
});

Attempts
[1/3] Use global route beforeEach hook
This doesn't work for currently unknown reason even if its usage feels the most appropriate to handle the visibility of that inner/non-route component on route path change.
The issue is that the InnerPartialComponent does not respect the variable used in its v-if directive and stays visible during the transition even if the hook handler gets executed. It may be even the order of the execution or the Virtual DOM gets not rendered to the actual DOM during the transition indeed.
To clarify, while checking out the documentation and source code of Vue Route (v3.6.5), 'noticed method beforeEach that is available globally in $router, apparently:
// ...
export default class VueRouter {
  // ...
  beforeHooks: Array<?NavigationGuard>
  // ...

  beforeEach (fn: Function): Function {
    return registerHook(this.beforeHooks, fn)
  }

  // ...
}
// ...

function registerHook (list: Array<any>, fn: Function): Function {
  list.push(fn)
  return () => {
    const i = list.indexOf(fn)
    if (i > -1) list.splice(i, 1)
  }
}

Source

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  /* must call `next` */
})

router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
  /* must call `next` */
})

router.afterEach((to, from) => {})

All three methods return a function that removes the registered guard/hook.
Source

A general test:

I.e. this.innerBarVisible = false (set in the route change hook) does not affect the "InnerBar" component during the transition.
Related
- vuejs/vue-router/issues/1106 (Remove beforeEach hooks...);
- vuejs/vue-router/issues/2341 (Remove all beforeEach, afterEach, beforeResolve...);
- vuejs/vue-router/issues/938 (Suggestion for guard: beforeRouteUpdate...).
[2/3] Use event @leave Vue built-in component transition
For example, https://jsfiddle.net/wy9mu0cf. It feels like the event is not passed deep enough, where component InnerPartialComponent doesn't handle it.
Related answer (Fire event when changing route before DOM changes and outside the route itself?...).
[3/3] Watch $route inside InnerPartialComponent
This doesn't work since the watcher gets removed before it actually handles the change the moment InnerPartialComponent gets "destroyed" on page change.
Related answer (Vuejs: Event on route change...).
Workarounds
[1/2] Change DOM directly
We could use change the DOM directly via querySelectorAll for instance, but the whole purpose of Virtual DOM or Vue disappears then, doesn't it?
A changed handler of "Attempt #1":
beforeTransitionLeave(el) {
  console.log('beforeTransitionLeave', el.id);
                
  el.querySelectorAll('#innerBar').forEach((el) => {
    if (!(el instanceof HTMLDivElement)) {
      return;
    }

    el.style.display = 'none';
  })
}

A general test.
[2/2] Dispatch a CustomEvent in beforeRouteLeave
A somewhat odd workaround is to dispatch a CustomEvent in beforeRouteLeave in the "route component" and change a prop of that InnerPartialComponent that has VueRecaptcha inside to control its visibility like <InnerPartialComponent :is-captcha-visible="isCaptchaVisible" /> and then <VueRecaptcha v-show="isCaptchaVisible" /> inside.
<!-- File: ./mixins/SomeMixin.ts -->

import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  layout: 'main',
  transition: 'scroll-x-transition',
  // ...

  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('before-route-leave', {
      detail: { to, from }
    }));

    next();
  }
});

<!-- File: ./components/PartialComponent.vue -->

<template>
  <div>
    <InnerPartialComponent v-if="isCaptchaVisible" ref="recaptcha" :site-key="reCaptchaSiteKey" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import InnerPartialComponent from '~/components/InnerPartialComponent.vue';
import config from '~/utils/config';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'PartialComponent',

  components: {
    InnerPartialComponent
  },

  data() {
    return {
      reCaptchaSiteKey: '' as string
    }
  },

  computed: {
    isCaptchaVisible(): boolean {
      return (this.reCaptchaSiteKey as string).length > 0
    }
  },

  created() {
    if (process.client) {
      this.reCaptchaSiteKey = config.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY as string;

      window.addEventListener('before-route-leave', () => {
        if (process.client) {
          this.reCaptchaSiteKey = '';
        }
      }, { once: true });
    }
  },
});

This works, but... it feels quite odd and unreliable.
